# Dynamical properties of Laughlin states

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-hall-effect

I have been studying the theory of fractional quantum Hall liquids in Xiao-Gang Wen's book "Quantum field theory of many-body systems" and at some point I came across problem 7.3.2. which goes as follows.

To understand the dynamical properties of Laughlin states, we consider the following Maxwell-Chern-Simons effective theory:

$\mathcal{L}=-\frac{m}{4\pi}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda}a_\mu\partial_\nu a_\lambda +\frac{1}{2g_1}e^2-\frac{1}{2g_2}b^2$,

where $a=a_\mu dx^\mu$ a $\text{U}(1)$ gauge field, $f=da$ is the field strength tensor, $(1/2)\varepsilon^{ij}f_{ij}=b$ is the magnetic field and $e_i=f_{0i}$ is the electric field, $g_1$ and $g_2$ are coupling constants, and $m$ is an integer. We are instructed to find the equations of motion for $e$ and $b$ and to find the energy gap. Then, assuming that the energy gap of the Laughlin state is of the order of $q^2/m^2\ell_B$ and the size of the quasihole is of the order of $\ell_B$ we are supposed to estimate $g_1$ and $g_2$.

In the above Lagrangian density, we have different couplings $g_1$ and $g_2$, so to take this into account I have written the Maxwell term in the form

$\frac{1}{2g_1}e^2-\frac{1}{2g_2}b^2=-\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{|G|}G^{\mu\nu}G^{\lambda\rho}f_{\mu\lambda}f_{\nu\rho}$,

where $G$ is an artificial flat metric tensor which assumes the form

$G=G_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu}=-(\sqrt{g_1}/\sqrt{g_2})dt^2 +(\sqrt{g_2}/\sqrt{g_1})d\textbf{x}^2$.

Then, by introducing the Hodge dual of $f$ with respect to $G$, $*f=f_{\mu}dx^\mu=(1/2)\sqrt{|G|}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda}G_{\lambda\sigma}f_{\mu\nu}dx^{\sigma}$, it is possible to show (since $G$ is flat) that the equation of motion for $f$ reduces to

$\Big(-G^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu} +(m/2\pi)^2\Big)f^\lambda=0$,

which further simplifies to

$\sqrt{(g_1/g_2)}\Big[(g_2/g_1)\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} -\nabla^2 + (m/2\pi)^2\sqrt{(g_2/g_1)}\Big]f^{\lambda}=0$.

From this equation, I can conclude that the speed of propagation of the excitations is $c=\sqrt{g_1/g_2}$. Moreover, the quantity $M^2\equiv (m/2\pi)^2\sqrt{(g_2/g_1)}$ acts as a mass, and therefore it is responsible for the gap of the excitations.

I am stuck at the part of estimating the values of $g_1$ and $g_2$. My guess would be to say something like $c$ should be of the order of $\hbar/\ell_B$ and $M$ of the order of $e^2/m^2\ell_B$, is this it? The second statement follows from the suggestion in the Problem, but the first one is not at all obvious to me.

I would gladly appreciate a full solution or some pointers.

Thanks in advance!